# Goの文字列比較

Tags: go

Goでstring型の変数とuint型の変数の比較を行いたいのですが、どのように書けばいいのでしょうか

例えば下記にように書いたところ、同じなのにfalseになってしまいました。

```html
if srtId == string(uintId){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

文字列で比較したい場合は、`unitId`を<del>`fmt.Sprintf("%d", uintId)`</del>`strconv.Itoa(unitId)`で文字列に変換する必要がありそうです。

`string(unitId)`は、unitIdの文字コードを元に変換するので、例えば、

```
a := uint(33)
fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %s", string(a))
```

を実行すると

```
Hello, playground !
```

と表示されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます!!できました!

Comment: 特別なフォーマットが不要であり、効率が重視される状況では `fmt.Sprintf` よりも [`strconv.Itoa`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) を使うようにしてください。

Comment: 修正しました！（だけだと短すぎて投稿できなかった。。。

Comment: @KoRoN 様
strconv.Itoaではuintをstrに変換できません。`(type uint) as type int in argument to strconv.Itoa`このようにintでないとでてしまいました

Comment: では `strconv.FormatUint` を使ってください。 Itoaが書かれたドキュメントを、すこし探せば見つかりますよ。